# F# deedle concat string columns

Tags: f#, deedle

I have a `Frame` with two columns of `String`,

```
let first = Series.ofValues(["a";"b";"c"])
let second = Series.ofValues(["d";"e";"f"])
let df = Frame(["first"; "second"], [first; second])
```

How do I produce a third column as the concatenation of the two columns? 
In `python` `pandas`, this can be achieved with simple `+` operator, but `deedle` gives error if i do that,

```
error FS0043: No overloads match for method 'op_Addition'.
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you want is to have something that returns something like:

```
Series.ofValues(["ad"; "be"; "cf"])
```

Then I think you need to define an addition operator with something like this:

```
let additionOperator = (fun (a:string) (b:string) -> (a + b))
```

And then you can add them like this:

```
Series.zipInto additionOperator first second
```

I get as the result:

```
val it : Series<int,string> = series [ 0 => ad; 1 => be; 2 => cf]
```

However if you are alright with tuples as your result, you can just use:

```
Series.zip first second
```

Answer (score 1):

I come across this after facing the same issue, the trick is to get the values as seq and use Seq.map2 to concat the two seqs, my solution is

```
let first = Series.ofValues(["a";"b";"c"])
let second = Series.ofValues(["d";"e";"f"])
let df = Seq.map2 (fun x y -> x+y) first.Values second.Values
         |> Series.ofValues
         |> (fun x -> Frame.addCol "third" x (Frame(["first"; "second"], [first; second])))
```

Result:

```
df.Print()
     first second third
0 -> a     d      ad
1 -> b     e      be
2 -> c     f      cf
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would work... Clearly not the most beautiful way to write it but... Will try to do some time testing later.

```
    let df3c = df |> Frame.mapRows (fun _ b -> b.GetAt(0).ToString() + b.GetAt(1).ToString())
                  |> (fun a -> Frame.addCol "test" a df)
```